# Big Oh Notation - between exponents and log function

Tags: big-o

Need help to find the `big Oh` expression for

> f(n) = 5n(n + 1)/2 + 75n log n + 45n + 729

I don't know if its `5n^2` or `n log n`.

Which of these has the higher order or importance?

Comment: The fastest-growing term dominates, so it's O(n^2). BTW, Big-O notation ignores constants, so never put constants like 5 into your Big-O expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the 5 from 5n^2 so both choices lose their coefficients. And n^2 grows much more quickly than nlogn.